# PHP OOP read csv file using constructor

Tags: php, csv, oop

I want echo my whole CSV file with using the constructor in PHP OOP.
Anyone an idea how to do this? I put it in code snippet because the code function doesn't work.

Here the CSV file: http://www.filedropper.com/cars_1

```html
 <?php

class Csv {

    private $file; 

    public function __construct($filename, $mode) {
        $this->file = fopen($filename, $mode); 
        return $this->file;
    }

    public function endFile() {
        return feof($this->file); 
    }

    public function getCSV($mode) {
        return fgetcsv($this->file, $mode);
    } 
    
    public function setFile(){
    include 'test.csv';
    }

    public function close() {
        fclose($this->file); 
    }
}

include_once ('csv.php');

$f = fopen("test.csv", "r");
echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table></body></html>";

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the purpose of a `constructor` is to configure the object, not to perform actions. Your file opening action is a big no-no there.

Secondly, a PHP constructor can not have a `return` statement. It may be said that the constructor returns the object itself.

Thirdly, to run through the class code, the object must be instantiated with

```
new Csv($filename, $mode);
```

Maybe this is what you were aiming for:

```
class CsvReader {

    private $file; 

    public function __construct($filename) {
        $this->file = $filename;
    }

    // Returns and bi-dimensional array iterable with foreach
    public function getCsv() {

        $csv = [];

        if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
                $csv[] = $data;
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }


        return $csv;
    } 

}
```

and

```
$reader = new CsvReader('test.csv');
var_dump($reader->getCsv());
```